# SharePoint on Office 365 Questions please? About to embark on it

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, office-365

I realize it's time I get acquainted with SharePoint Online or 365 not sure if they are one and the same. I do know that SharePoint comes with Office 365.
As a developer, is there anything more I would need or is it all encompassed in Office 365?

- Is SharePoint Designer needed or would it work with SharePoint 365?
- Can one still build workflows from scratch in Office 365 or are they all apps of some sort?
- And lastly is there an ability to use InfoPath 2013 at all with Office 365 or equivalent?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is "SharePoint Designer" needed or would it work with SharePoint Online?**

**Yes,** it works with SharePoint Online, and it still needed.

**Can one still build workflows from scratch in SharePoint Online?**

**Yes,** you can use the SharePoint Designer to build workflows in SharePoint 
Online. you can also use [Microsoft Flow](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/) to create automated workflows.

**And lastly is there an ability to use InfoPath 2013 at all with Office 365 or equivalent?**

**Yes,** you can use Infopath with SharePoint Online.

> **Note:** InfoPath 2013 and SharePoint Designer 2013 will be the last versions of those products meanwhile Microsoft will continue to
>   support custom workflows built with SharePoint Designer and hosted on
>   SharePoint Server 2016 and Office 365.
>
> The support for InfoPath 2013 and SharePoint Designer 2013 will match
>   the support lifecycle for SharePoint Server 2016, running until 2026.

**Regarding InfoPath alternative**

Until now, Microsoft hasn't announced an explicit alternative for SharePoint Designer. however, you can use **PowerApps** as an alternative for Infopath in SharePoint online

- **PowerApps** is a service for building and using custom business apps
  that connect to your data and work across the web and mobile –
  without the time and expense of custom software development.
- **PowerApps** also introduce a **logic Flow** to create automated workflows between your favorite apps and services to get notifications, synchronize files, collect data, and more.

For more details check [SharePoint Designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in SharePoint Server 2016, What’s the alternatives ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Mohamed you are the best!!!!!